# Im using react Js, I have a list of Objects, the first object has a elements of array same thing with second Object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a List of objects here

```
const List_objects = [
 { 
   Product = A,
   Price = 20
 },
 {
   Product = B,
   Price = 21
 }
]
```

and I have a person_data with

```js
const [person_data,setPerson_Data] = useState({
  Product : 0,
  Price = :0
})
```

and i have a onClick function here

```
const handleClick = e => {
  setPerson_Data({
      Product: String(List_objects.map(e=>e.Product)),
      Price : String(List_objects.map(e=>e.Price))
   })
```

and when I print via console.log this will be the result

```
 {
    Product: A,B,
    Price : 20,21
  }
```

and I wanted to do it in reverse

from these

```
{
   Product: A,B,
   Price : 20,21
}
```

into these

```
[
  { 
    Product = A,
    Price = 20
  },
  {
    Product = B,
    Price = 21
  }
]
```

I am 3rd yr ComEng student and i am developing a Online Inventory System using React JS it will really a great help in my school specially my career as aspirant developer

do you guys any idea how to execute it ? or maybe some alternative also it will help if there is sample code

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: yes I do use that but i dunno how to execute it i keep getting an undefined error

Comment: please dont dislike this post T_T

Comment: Please read the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible ways go create the array from it. One uses a [Generator](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_sync-generators.html), the other uses [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const input = {
  Product: "A,B",
  Price: "20,21",
};

function* fromObjectGenerator(obj) {
  const products = obj.Product.split(",");
  const prices = obj.Price.split(",");
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    yield {
      Product: products[i],
      Price: prices[i],
    };
  }
}

function fromObject(obj) {
  const products = obj.Product.split(",");
  const prices = obj.Price.split(",");
  return [...Array(products.length)].map((_, idx) => ({
    Product: products[idx],
    Price: prices[idx],
  }));
}

console.log([...fromObjectGenerator(input)]);
console.log(fromObject(input));
```

> Please note: Both implementations assume that the number of `products` matches the number of `prices` but which little adjustments it could also work if that was not the case.